# Content Security Policy (CSP) blocking jquery

Tags: jquery, content-security-policy

I'm adding a CSP to all responses with a randomly generated nonce:

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'nonce-PWLxo3xnlnYSljtj87674pq9dK3CkDz/2n/Vzw4N1c0=' 'self'
```

However, it's blocking jquery:

```
Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'nonce-PWLxo3xnlnYSljtj87674pq9dK3CkDz/2n/Vzw4N1c0=' 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.
```

The dev tools point to this line in jquery, though I'm not certain it's the actual culprit:

```
target.appendChild( elem );
```

Part of this function:

```
    append: function() {
        return domManip( this, arguments, function( elem ) {
            if ( this.nodeType === 1 || this.nodeType === 11 || this.nodeType === 9 ) {
                var target = manipulationTarget( this, elem );
                target.appendChild( elem );
            }
        } );
    },
```

Since it is in an external file and not an inline script, I'm not clear on why jquery is being blocked at all.

Setting an error breakpoint in Safari stops at this line:

```
a.querySelectorAll("\\\f");
```

and:

```
el.querySelectorAll( "*,:x" );
```

Not sure what those variables are, it's minified javascript.  But that doesn't seem to have anything to do with running a script.  Then it stops here:

```
if ( ( support.matchesSelector = rnative.test( ( matches = docElem.matches ||
                    docElem.webkitMatchesSelector ||
                    docElem.mozMatchesSelector ||
                    docElem.oMatchesSelector ||
                    docElem.msMatchesSelector ) ) ) ) {

                    assert( function( el ) {

                        // Check to see if it's possible to do matchesSelector
                        // on a disconnected node (IE 9)
                        support.disconnectedMatch = matches.call( el, "*" );

                        // This should fail with an exception
                        // Gecko does not error, returns false instead
                        matches.call( el, "[s!='']:x" );
                        rbuggyMatches.push( "!=", pseudos );
                    } );
                }
```

on `matches.call()`.  Then on `fullReload()` called from within a success handler in `function changeView`.  `fullReload` does this:

```
function fullReload() {
  window.location = window.location.pathname
}
```

according to Safari.

Comment: Have you tried to add `report-only-mode` in your CSP entry? This reports the error message as a warning, but doesn't cause a failure in the web page. Maybe you can get a better visibility on where the issue originates.

Comment: @TasosK. I did, I just got the same information.

Comment: Check the dom, is a `<script>` without  a `nonce` attribute being added by an extension or something?

Answer (score 0):

I would look through your code to see anywhere you are calling `.append` if somehow a script tag is getting included. The error suggests an attempt to change the inline scripts in the document without providing a nonce to authorize the changed script.

Somewhat contrived example:

**index.html**

```
<html>
   <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/test.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="testElement">Test Element</div>
      <script nonce="randomrandomrandom">
$( "#testElement" ).on( "click", function() { doTest( $( "#testElement" ) ); } );
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```
function doTest(element) {
  var scriptElement = document.createElement( "script" );
  scriptElement.text = "function xssInject () { alert(1); } xssInject();";
  element.append( scriptElement );
}
```

**.htaccess**

```
Header add Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'nonce-randomrandomrandom' 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com;"
```

To debug this exception in a browser (like Safari) that will throw an exception in the debugger for a CSP issue, you want to perform whatever actions are needed to cause the issue then step through any exceptions until you get a break that says it will throw a CSP exception next. It should be on the line you've already identified (appendChild). The call stack of that will go back through jQuery code into the application's JS code. Looking at it unminified will be easier. Getting the values from local variables that are being passed to the jQuery function (likely `.append()`) from your code should hopefully identify the element that is causing the issue, though maybe not why it is there.

Note that jQuery will throw some exceptions from `.querySelectorAll()` calls on page load just by including the jQuery library. They will be unrelated to the CSP exception. If your CSP issue is happening on page load too then stepping through the exceptions until your see the one that is causing the CSP exception is going to be needed.

Comment: Experiments indicate that just manipulating the jQuery event handlers on an element from an external script does not trigger the protection. There may be a more complicated manipulation that introduces javascript to the DOM non-obviously though.

Comment: Various elements being appended, but I cannot find any instance of a script being appended.

Comment: Depending on which browser you are using, setting a breakpoint on exception might give you the call stack. When I tried this in Chrome, it wouldn't break and give a call stack for this type of exception; but when I used Safari, it did and showed me exactly which call from my code was violating the policy. Whether I'm just not seeing the right options in Chrome to make it show the call stack, I'm not sure. What browser are you testing with?

Comment: I have been using Chrome but I'll try it with Safari, thanks.

Comment: I got the various places it stops in the Safari debugger, but none of them look like anything appending or running a script.  Still looking into what `fullReload` does though.  I have added the debugger results to the question.

Comment: Two thoughts: do you have any inline script on attributes (e.g. onclick="javascript:void(0)" in the page; and can you post the call stack for the exception from the `querySelectorAll` call?

Comment: The call stack is just a bunch of references to line numbers in application.unminified.js - would pasting in each referred-to line be useful?  Nothing like `onclick="javascript"` in the page, according to Safari web tools.

Comment: I misinterpreted something you said, and didn't click to the potential difference between the CSP exception situation and the other exceptions on the page. I've updated the answer with a bit more detail. I'd suggest trying to get the call stack and the local variables for the exact call from your code to the jQuery code that throws the CSP exception.

Comment: Sorry I haven't been able to work on this but I will get back to it.